# Cannot import the CSS in JSF pages

Tags: jsf-2, oracle11g, jdeveloper, oracle-adf

I'm learning to use ADF on Oracle jDeveloper 11g.
I created an ADF Fusion Web Application (with the WebLogic webserver) and I created a JSF page under `\ViewController\public_html`. Then I created a CSS skin file (for JSF) and I put it under `\ViewController\WebContent\resources\css\`

I want to apply such style rules to the JSF page. To do this I put it into such page the line

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="prova.css" id="CASD"/>
```

where `prova.css` is the name of the CSS file I've created.

It doesn't work, neither using `/css` instead of `css` or `/resources/css`, etc.

Comment: I've never used JDeveloper, but shouldn't that JSF file go in `/WebContent` as well? As to the problem, please elaborate "doesn't work". What exactly are you seeing in the generated HTML output? What exactly does the client (webbrowser) say about the resource?

Comment: what do you see in the rendered html source code for that page?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The browser (firefox) and the the jedit preview simply ignore the CSS, so that the page without any style is rendered. Furthermore, I examinated the generated HTML code with firefox: any <link type=".../css" ....> tag exists. If I create the CSS skin (using the jdeveloper editor) and I say to apply this theme to all the pages (some details are written in the xml config files) it works.

Comment: So, the JSF-generated `<link>` element is correct? Then this is not a JSF problem. Perhaps the CSS file is just empty or something.

Comment: No no the tag <h:outputStylesheet ...> is ignored by ADF and the attributes library and name where suggested by the code completion of jdeveloper so I think they are correct and the CSS file exists and it's not empty. I can't understand! Is the jdeveloper 11.2 stable?

Comment: I mean, I can't import any css style in my jsf pages.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `<af:resource type="css" source="your source path here" />` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You shoud make a skin and add your page. When you make a skin 
the name of skin is set in `trinidad-config.xml` in your project:

```
<skin-family>skin2(name of skin)</skin-family>
```